# Is it better to use CSS / HTML to adjust an image size, or save multiple versions of the image?

Tags: image, resize

Up until now, when a user has uploaded an image, I have been saving several different versions of it for use throughout my site. As the site has grown, so have the numbers of sizes needed.

At the moment each uploaded image is sized in to about 6 new images and saved on the server.

The downside is that every time I need to create a new size (right now, for instance, I'm making a new size for an image gallery), I have to cycle through all the thousands of images and re-cut a new size for each.

Whereas, when I started, it was a nice quick way to avoid resizing images on the fly, now it's starting to turn into a nightmare.

Is it better to continue saving different sizes, and just deal with the overhead, or is it better at this point to get maybe 3 general sizes, and resize them on the fly as needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Resizing" images using html/css (e.g., specifying height & width) is generally not what you want to do - it results in poorly scaled images with artifacts from the resize, and is inefficient as the user is potentially downloading a much larger file than they actually need.

Rather, having some kind of server-side solution to allow for on-the-fly resizing is probably what you want. I'd recommend using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) - combined with the implementation for your favorite language and some web-server voodoo (e.g., using .htaccess for Apache), you can easily have /path/to/yourimage.png?50x50 fire a call to a resize script that resizes the image, saves it in a cache folder, and outputs the resized file to the browser. This is better all around - you get proper resizing, your user only downloads the exact file they need, and the end-result is cached so your resize action only occurs once. Check out [Image::Magick::Thumbnail](http://search.cpan.org/~lgoddard/Image-Magick-Thumbnail-0.06b/lib/Image/Magick/Thumbnail.pm) for an example (in perl)

Edit - if you respond to this with what server-side language/framework you are using, I would be happy to point you in the direction of a thumbnail/resizing implementation of ImageMagick or something else for your platform.

Comment: It's for ASP.NET, but http://imageresizing.net/ allows you to get resized versions dynamically through the image querystring. TimThumb for PHP is well known, might give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple versions.

Some browsers simply don't scale these things well and you end up with choppy nasty in the image, bad pixelation, etc...

The exception could be if you know all the images are photographic.  Then have versions for your larger sizes, but shrinking could be ok.  But if these have illustration or text, the effect will be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

```
.resize {  
  width: 200px;  
  height : auto;  
}  

.resize {  
  width: auto;  
  height : 300px;  
}
```

Comment: It would be so much better if you explained your solution.